# picture library -Slides view office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery-ajax

I am using a Picture Slide Show web part on a team site. Whenever i click the previous or next button my Site page is refreshed, which I don't want. I want my picture slide show web part to be updated rather than my page getting refreshed.

I know this can be done by AJAX, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

For Reference: [How to add a slideshow to SharePoint Site](http://sharepointmaven.com/add-slideshow-sharepoint-site/)

You can also reference this page for design [WIX Template](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1329?originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%3Fcriteria%3Dslide&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=2). In this page you can see the different page design with code(By View source code) and also you can create your own design and get the code for that designed page.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I add the Picture Library SlideShow web part to a site page in SharePoint Online, however the page doesn’t refresh when I click next/previous button.

Try to create a new simple page and add this web part check if the issue exists.

Comment: Not picture library web part.  It's out of the box slides view in picture library.